# Cómo corregir posición del botón?

Tags: html, css

Estoy haciendo unas cartas, y el boton de Mas Info o Leer Mas Me queda abajo aca les dejo el codigo css y html. si alguien me ayuda les agradezco.

lo que quiero es que el texto quede acomodado y alineado con la el bloque de la carta no se si me explico. es como esta en la imagen es acomodarlo

```css
.card-container {
    background-color: rgb(179, 179, 34);
    height: 150px;
    width: 190px;
    box-shadow: inset;
    border-radius: 4px;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: #30343a;
}
.card-button{
    background-color: white;
    padding: 10px 100px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: #30343a;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.card-title {
  text-align: center;
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.card-text {
    text-align: center;
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
            <br>
            <h3 class="card-title">Lobatos</h3>
            <p class="card-text">6 a 11 años</p>
            <br>
            <br>

            <a href="#" class="card-button">Mas info</a>
        </div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. Por favor, relee tu pregunta, mira que no necesitabas añadir spam y revisa dónde nos dices qué es lo que quieres que pase. Ahora ve a [edit], edita tu pregunta y explícanos sin spam, qué es lo que quieres que haga ese CSS en ese HTML

Comment: listo, gracias perdon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba de la siguiente manera:

Al contenedor padre le puse un `padding: 10px` (el `height` es opcional, porque debe crecer en caso de haber más contenido)

A la etiqueta `a` que actúa como botón le puse un margen vertical de 10px y horizontalmente auto. También le puse un `padding: 10px 0` (0 porque ya está centrado el texto, y si era 100px ya sobresalía del contenedor); y `display: block` para que esté debajo de los contenidos (`p`)

IMPORTANTE: en este caso no la etiqueta `br` para separar los contenidos. Usa `margin: 10px auto`, `margin: 1rem 0`, etc. por cada objeto hijo con `display: block` si es necesario.

Eso fue uno de tu error: el `br`. Porque el contenedor padre tiene un `height` fijo, pero había mucha separación entre sus contenidos con los `br` y algunos objetos salían fuera del contenedor

```css
.card-container {
    background-color: rgb(179, 179, 34);
    height: 150px;
    width: 190px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    box-shadow: inset;
    border-radius: 4px;
    align-items: center;
    box-shadow: #30343a;
}
.card-button{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    box-shadow: #30343a;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: block
}

.card-title {
  text-align: center;
  color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.card-text {
    text-align: center;
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
```

```html
<div class="card-container">
            
            <h3 class="card-title">Lobatos</h3>
            <p class="card-text">6 a 11 años</p>
            

            <a href="#" class="card-button">Mas info</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Gracias eso era lo que buscaba, pero te hago una consulta ¿como le puedo hacer un hover al boton que al poner el mouse sobre el boton nos salga el mismo texto con este signo https://imgur.com/ImTqL5Z?

Comment: Eso es propio del navegador, y funciona con las etiquetas `a`. Se podría evitar haciendo un botón normal, y al hacer click se abra el enlace que contiene el botón en un `data-` por ejemplo.

Comment: @TobiasCampomenosi no olvides marcar está respuesta con ✓ si te sirvió

Comment: perdon, por las preguntas de novato es que soy nuevo en css y html. https://prnt.sc/DO6HMx6UINeD se puede hacer que allá una separacion entre cada una y que no este muy pegado del margen izquierdo que quede separado del margen

Comment: @TobiasCampomenosi sí pues que si. Prueba con: `margin: auto;` o también `margin: auto; margin-left: 10px` o la distancia que deceas

Comment: gracias por la ayuda capo, entendí a la perfección la explicación :), una ultima pregunta ¿como se hace para poner un sombreado? @Narciso Aifuz

Comment: @TobiasCampomenosi `box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px 2px #123` y juega con los números